# Standardized numpy/scipy `asarray` decorator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, decorator

Is there a standardized decorator for applying `asarray` on function arguments?

I.e. something where I could write:

```
@array_args  # this decorator automatically calls asarray on arguments
def f(x,y):
     return x/y
```

instead of

```
def f(x,y):
    (x,y)=(numpy.asarray(x), numpy.asarray(y))
     return x/y
```

I've only found this [discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2006-March/007290.html), so I could pull the decorator there; but I'd 
prefer to use a version that has been integrated into `numpy`.

Comment: I doubt that exists -- Especially since writing the decorator yourself is pretty simple ...

Comment: I figured it was so simple that one of the numpy developers would have put it in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up with,

```
import scipy # numpy could work too
from functools import wraps
def asarray_strictnumeric( obj ):
    ''' only convert if the result is a numerical array. '''
    tmp=scipy.asarray(obj)
    if tmp.dtype.kind in 'iufc':
        return tmp
    else:
        return obj

def array_args(f):
    ''' Decorator: 
        - converts numerical positional arguments to arrays,
        - leaves non-numerical positional arguments alone,
        - leaves all keywords alone.
    '''
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        args=[asarray_strictnumeric(x) for x in args]
        return f( *args, **kwds )
    return wrapper
```

but @promanow s answer was a useful starting point.

Comment: You should use numpy, not scipy.  `scipy.asarray` is just an alias for `numpy.asarray`; using it creates an unnecessary dependency on scipy.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK it doesn't exist, but it's quite simple to write one:

```
from functools import wraps


def array_args(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        arrays = map(np.asarray, args)
        return func(*arrays)

    return wrapper
```